# SQL query to get filters with expected values for a web view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

I've got a web-application that requires data from a db. It is a simple list of jobs where each job has certain tags and also a location. Now I want to get a list that gives me all possible filter options... like this:

```
FILTER-ATTRIBUTE    FILTER-CATEGORY    MATCHING-JOBS
programming         tag                9
car-washing         tag                3
cooking             tag                13
Munich              city               16
San Diego           city               9
```

What I do have is a query with UNIONS, but this is first of all not really fast and it's ugly to filter...because I need several WHERE clauses there if the user applies a filter (e.g. if San Diego is selected, I will restrict the query to return only tags with relevance to San Diego. In this example, programming only).

```
SELECT
  jt.tag_name as name,
  COUNT(jt.job_id) as available_jobs,
  'tag' as filter_cat
FROM job_tag_new jt WHERE jt.job_id IN (20002,30002) GROUP BY(jt.tag_name)
UNION
SELECT
  j.company as name,
  COUNT(j.id) as available_jobs,
  'company' as filter_cat
FROM job j WHERE j.id IN (20002,30002) GROUP BY(j.company)
UNION
SELECT
  l.city as name,
  COUNT(j.id) as available_jobs,
  'city' as filter_cat
FROM job j left join location l on l.id = j.location WHERE j.id IN (20002,30002) GROUP BY(l.city)
```

Last but not least... there is not only one table because several tables/objects can be used for filtering ;-)

Any suggestions would be nice. Even if I should take a complete different approach!

Regards,
Martin

Comment: for a start replace all of your `UNION` with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: UNION and UNION ALL won't make any difference in this case, as there is a literal that is different in each of the component sets and there fore there won't any duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, I came across an interesting approach and I would like to share this with with you:

```
SELECT
    name,
    COUNT(job_id)
FROM   (
    SELECT j.id AS job_id, loc.city, j.company, jt.tag_name
    FROM job_tag_new jt
    LEFT JOIN job j ON jt.job_id = j.id
    LEFT JOIN location loc ON loc.id = j.location
) base
CROSS APPLY (
VALUES
    ([city]),
    ([company]),
    ([tag_name])
) 
V(name)
GROUP BY name
```

The only thing which is missing here is to get a separate column that tells me the column name before the cross apply. Maybe someone has an idea for this ;-)

Comment: I like it!; I added the column name in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

there are two other approaches that you may want to explore:

windowing:

```
select distinct
tag, location, company,
count(id) over(partition by tag) thistag, 
count(id) over(partition by location) thisloc,
count(id) over(partition by company) thiscompany
from job
order by tag, location
```

aggregation with cube:

```
select location, tag, company, count(id) from job
group by location, tag, company with cube
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, definitely an interesting approach. Unfortunately this would have required additional processing in the application to get rid of the unnecessary combinations. What do you think about the solution I've posted (will post in a minute)?

Comment: I like the approach you proposed, it's very good; I added another answer to include the column name using your approach

Answer (score 0):

to include column name:

```
SELECT
    name,
    cname,
    COUNT(job_id)
FROM   (
    SELECT j.id AS job_id, loc.city, j.company, jt.tag_name
    FROM job_tag_new jt
    LEFT JOIN job j ON jt.job_id = j.id
    LEFT JOIN location loc ON loc.id = j.location
) base
CROSS APPLY (
VALUES
    ([city], 'city'),
    ([company], 'company'),
    ([tag_name], 'tag')
) 
V(NAME,cname)
GROUP BY name,cname
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint... too obvious :-)